# Get parameters out from QueryDSL Predicate Object

Tags: java, spring, rest, predicate, querydsl

I use QueryDSL predicate object with a spring REST endpoint to retrieve and query param values.

```
@GetMapping("/{subjectId}/students")
@RolesAllowed( {Roles.PLATFORM_ADMIN, Roles.USER})
public List<StudentResponse> getAllStudents(@PathVariable final String subjectId,                                
                                      @QuerydslPredicate(root = Student.class) final Predicate predicate) {     

        final Predicate searchPredicate = studentPredicate()
                .predicate(predicate)
                .subjectId(subjectId)
                .build();
        return studentService.findBySubjectId(subjectId, searchPredicate);

}
```

student Class contains **studentId** and **studentName** attributes;

Now, if someone invokes https://hostname/{subjectId}/students?studentId=1234&studentName=test

Then above code generates the predicate object with param values. But I need to get above 2 param values out from predicate object for further processing apart from the db querying. I don't see any supportive method from predicate object to retrieve values out. So how can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no straightforward way to do this.
However You can try this.

`predicate.toString();` ---> This would print user.Studentid=1234 && user.studentName=test
From this, you can do a string split.

Another way is with

`predicate.getClass());` ----> This will give you the class name like

class `com.querydsl.core.types.PredicateOperation` (in case of more than one query conditions)

class `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.BooleanOperation` (in case of single query condition).

With this you could typecast predicate to corresponding type and then do `getArgs()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a `QuerydslBinderCustomizer`, the string is not as easy to parse.

Another approach is to let Spring bind your query params to the predicate root class, `Student` in your example. To do this, simply add another method argument of type `Student` to your controller method. Then, your query params matching `Student` props are accessible without string parsing.

```
@GetMapping("/{subjectId}/students")
@RolesAllowed( {Roles.PLATFORM_ADMIN, Roles.USER})
public List<StudentResponse> getAllStudents(
    Student student, // add this arg to easily access the Student related query params
    @PathVariable final String subjectId,                                
    @QuerydslPredicate(root = Student.class) final Predicate predicate) {     
    
    // now you can get the id & name without parsing predicate.toString()
    student.getStudentId();
    student.getStudentName();
```