# How can extract params from querydsl Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, querydsl

As we know that Querydsl get Peageable and Predicate as parameters but how can I extract the params from this querydsl? because I must get the Id that I passed in postman so that I can use it.

That's my controller :

```
@GetMapping
    ResponseEntity<Page<MedicalDataDto>> getMedicalData(Pageable pageable, @QuerydslPredicate(root = MedicalData.class) Predicate predicate){
        return ResponseEntity.ok(medicalDataService.getMedicalData(pageable,predicate));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use class `com.querydsl.core.types.PredicateOperation` (in case of more than one query conditions)

use class `com.querydsl.core.types.dsl.BooleanOperation` (in case of single query condition).

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49146185/get-parameters-out-from-querydsl-predicate-object) is the similar question.